# I have two table in my database.I want to select record from one table if other table not that record

Tags: java, sql, database, select, oracle10g

I have two table "A" and "B". I want to select record from table "A" only if "B" table not that requested values according to given ID. In my code I pass my "ID" to select record. I want to select record from "A" table if only "B" table doesn't exist requested record.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results to better explain what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pretty much put that into SQL words

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE A
WHERE A.ID = ? 
AND A.ID NOT IN (
    SELECT B.ID 
    FROM TABLE B
    WHERE B.ID = ?
)
```

Use the `?` as placeholder with a `PreparedStatement` (safe) or replace them manually with the value you want (unsafe).